# What is the greatest decimal integer you can represent with $n$ cubes if each side bears a number 0-9?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was tinkering with a calendar my parents had with blocks for each month, and two cubes with varying integers on each side, a bit like dice. I quickly looked at their layout and saw that the maximum decimal number they could represent was 32, which I found quite pleasing since it nicely encapsulated the number of days in a month. I began to play around with an extension of the question - what maximum could I count to given three such cubes, or indeed any $n$ of them.

The first cube is laid out with the values {0,1,2,3,4,5} and the second has {6,7,8,9,1,2}. I built a third cube, just following the pattern and hand-checking my results, and found that a {3,4,5,6,7,8} cube could proceed up to 98. Since there's only one 9, this is the first place 3 cubes fails. 4 cubes, though, where the fourth is {9,0,1,2,3,4}, is much improved - they could go to 554, since there are not three 5s in this arrangement and making a change to accommodate that would fail at a lower integer.

So far, $n=1$ cubes can go up to 6, $n=2$ up to 32, $n=3$ up to 98, and $n=4$ up to 554.

I cannot for the life of me find a relationship in this pattern, and I'm struggling to generalize it. I assume a pattern exists, but I can't even guarantee that it does. The sequence {6,32,98,554} is not registered in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, and their prime factorizations seem unrelated.

If anybody sees a mistake, recognizes this problem/sequence, or knows how it might be generalized, I'd really appreciate the input. Thanks for the read and the time!

Comment: I don't get what this is. What are the cubes representing? How do the sets "proceed up to 98"

Comment: My bad, I should've clarified - laying out the cubes side by side so that the each (numbered) face is a place value in a decimal number. If there are two cubes, {0,1,2,3,4,5} and {6,7,8,9,1,2}, you could lay them side-by-side to "spell" any number 1 up to 32. Then the two cube setup fails to count to 33, since there's no more space to add the necessary second 3.

Comment: How does your $3$ cube example construct $4$, for example?

Comment: How did you get the number $5$ with two cubes?  The $5$ is on one cube.  But then you have to use the other cube.  It doesn't have a $0$.

Comment: Ah! I wasn't imagining all cubes being necessary to construct a number. Since 5 is on one cube, there's enough to build a 5 out of that set. This is... Admittedly arbitrary.

Comment: You could use the same side for 6 and 9, then put 0 on that cube.  Then you can do 04 and 05

Comment: I would say the maximum decimal number the two cubes can represent is $95,$ since it is possible to represent $95$ and not possible to represent anything larger. What interests you is that $33$ is the _minimum_ decimal number that the cubes _cannot_ represent using one or both cubes. Another way to put it is that the cubes can represent all numbers from $1$ to $32,$ but not $33.$

Comment: Note your numbers are all of the form ${aaaaaa}_{k+1}  - 1$.  And $a = 6\times n - 10k$ where all digits occur $k$ times on different cubes and the digits $1.... a$ will occur $k+1$ times (on different cubes) and fill up the remaining $6\times n -10k$ faces.

Answer (score 2):

Number your $n$ cubes $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7,8,9,0,1,2$ and $3,4,5,6,7,8$ and so on.

You have $6n$ faces.  Let $k$ but such that $10k \le 6n < 10(k+1)$.  Then all your digits will occur $k$ times on $k$ different cubes.  And if $a = 6n -10k> 0$ then the digits $1,... a$ will occur $k+1$ times on $k+1$ different cubes.

And so all number up to $\underbrace{(a+1)(a+1)......(a+1)}_k a$ will be possible and no higher (as you only have $k$ and not $k+1$ of the digit $a+1$).

.....

And no other numbering will allow you to get higher than that number.  The get $\underbrace{(a+1)(a+1)....(a+1)}(a+1)$,  that would require $k$ copies of the digits $a+2.... 9, 0$ and $k+1$ of the digits $1,....,a+1$.

That is, $10k + (a+1) = 6n + 1$ faces required and you only have $6n$ faces available